# Toolbar scroll from curve to normal with image overlap

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to create a layout like this :

[image]

I have this layout but the problem is that is not transparent the background also how do I add the circle image overlapped? I mean is like a circle and inside the imageView that I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curve_toolbar_bg"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_qr_creator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="-80dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

### EDIT

The thing is to achieve, when I scroll this toolbar becomes a line without the curve, and then the imageView keeps the same overlay in the toolbar or if possible is add in the right

My toolbar now looks as the image but I had to remove the CordinateLayout and appBarLayout but I guess now I can not keep it doing because I have no control of the scroll.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_create_qr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curve_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar_create_qr"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15" />
```